# Best way to validate related data update in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have two models:

1. User:

   - id
2. Post:

   - id
   - user_id

     - belongsTo `User`
   - text

I want to update a Post record, which way to validate user_id is better?

### Number 1

Pass `user_id` to controller with get method like:

```php
Route::post('/post/edit/{user_id}/{post_id}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

and validate it in controller:

```php
public function update($user_id, $post_id, Request $request){
   abort_if(!User::first($user_id), 404);

   $request->validate([
      'text' => 'string|...',
   ]);

   Post::findOrFail($post_id)->update([
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'text'    => $request->text,
   ]);
```

---

### Number 2

Pass `user_id` with hidden field with `POST` method like:

view:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}>
```

Routing:

```php
Route::post('/post/edit/{post_id}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

Controller:

```php
public function update($post_id, PostUpdate $request){
   Post::findOrFail($post_id)->update([
      'user_id' => $request->user_id,
      'text'    => $request->text,
   ]);
}
```

PostUpdate request:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'text' => 'string',
    ];
}
```

Which way is proper or better?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you ? if so accept it as "The answer", if not please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: In `Number 1`,  on `User::first(` , the param is a collumn name and `$user_id` isn't a collumn and will generate an error. You need probably a `find()` @jb997

Answer (score 2):

If the user is the authentified user, use the Auth::class

```
public function update($post_id, Request $request){
   $request->validate([
      'text' => 'string|...',
   ]);

   Post::findOrFail($post_id)->update([
      'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
      'text'    => $request->text,
   ]);
}
```

You can even make sure the post owner is the current user (which is better).

```
public function update($post_id, Request $request){
   $request->validate([
      'text' => 'string|...',
   ]);

   Post::where('user_id', \Auth::id())->findOrFail($post_id)->update([
      'text'    => $request->text,
   ]);
}
//or (and this is the proper way to do it. It does the same amout of queries and is way easier to read/maintain).
public function update($post_id, Request $request){
   $request->validate([
      'text' => 'string|...',
   ]);

   $user = \Auth::user();

   $post = $user->posts()->findOrFail($post_id);

   $post->text = $request->text;
   $post->save();
}
```

No need for the user validation since all of that is handled at login and the rest is maintained through middleware.

Route:

```
Route::post('/post/edit/{post_id}', 'PostController@update')->middleware('auth')->name('post.update');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another way for you. Work with [`middlewares`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction).

In the `gate` you can check the type of `user`, so `users` should be able to edit if they are the owner. In this case you can add some other rules just in one file and user everywhere you want.

In `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` define your gate:

```php
Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, \App\Post $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

Then in your routes `web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')
    ->name('edit_post')
    ->middleware('can:update-post,post');

Route::post('/edit/{post}', 'PostController@update')
    ->name('update_post')
    ->middleware('can:update-post,post');
```

Comment: Good answer, but doing `->middleware('can:update-post,post');` is not recommended, it is obfuscating code, this should be in his `PostUpdate` request's [`authorize`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests) method, that file has this particular responsibility.